# Update value of a variable without printing its value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `Employees` which have two columns `Year` and `UserCount`.
Table looks something like this

```
Year  UserCount

2001 400

2002 1000

2003 2000
```

Now I want to print the year and the difference between the subsequent UserCount of two years.

I want to output something like this.

```
Year UserCount

2001 400

2002 600

2003 1000
```

I thought of taking a variable and initializing it with `0` and updating its value after every iteration. This is the query that I came up with

```
SET @prev = 0;
select year, (UserCount - @prev) as diff, @prev := (UserCount) from Employees;
```

Though I'm getting the difference but it adds a new column too, `@prev := (Count)` Is there any way by which I could update the value of `prev` without printing its value?

Is there any other approach which is better than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add a value and subtract the same value in an expression, it cancels out.

```
select year, (UserCount - @prev + ((@prev:=UserCount)-UserCount)) as diff
from Employees;
```

But I question why you feel you need to do this. It shouldn't be a problem to have an extra column in a query result that you don't need. Your application code doesn't need to display it.

Answer (score 1):

You can conceal the column you need to handle this difference hack by using an outer query. This will remove the `:=` update column from the returned result set. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/918a75/1/0)

```
select year, diff
  from (
        select year, (UserCount - @prev) as diff, @prev := (UserCount) 
          from Employees
          join (select @prev:= 0) init
         order by year
       ) subquery
```

Notice a couple of things.

1. The initialization is moved to a join clause.
2. It's always smart to ORDER your tables. If you don't the result set ordering is unpredictable, which is bad.